# Is there any way to find all configured JsonDeserializers or at least to find JsonDeserializer for specific JavaType?

Tags: java, json, error-handling, jackson

I am writing error handler for Jackson deserialization exceptions and I am having trouble with getting deserializers for specific JavaType. The goal of the error handler is to find out if the target type for deserialization is scalar (String, URI, UUID or numbers) or it is an object. I am trying to find out it by getting the deserializer from deserialization context of my ObjectMapper and checking if it is StdScalarDeserializer or not but I am getting NullPointerException that tells me that config field of context object is null.

I am trying to handle the error that apears when I try to deserialize the following as BeanWithDouble:

```
{
  "bean_id": ["9223372036854775807","9223372036854775808"]
}
```

```
@Data
public class BeanWithDouble {

    @JsonProperty("bean_id")
    private Double id;
}
```

My code to handle the error:

```
  public void handle(MismatchedInputException mismatchedInputException) {
    Class<?> targetType = mismatchedInputException.getTargetType();
    Object processor = mismatchedInputException.getProcessor();
    JsonToken currentToken = null;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = null;
    DeserializationConfig deserializationConfig = null;
    DeserializationContext deserializationContext = null;
    if (processor instanceof JsonParser jsonParser) {
      ObjectCodec objectCodec = jsonParser.getCodec();
      if (objectCodec instanceof ObjectMapper) {
        objectMapper = (ObjectMapper) objectCodec;
        deserializationConfig = objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig();
        deserializationContext = objectMapper.getDeserializationContext();
        currentToken = jsonParser.getCurrentToken();
      }

    }
    if (currentToken != null) {
      TypeFactory typeFactory = deserializationConfig.getTypeFactory();
      JavaType javaType = typeFactory.constructType(targetType);
      JsonDeserializer<Object> jsonDeserializer;
      try {
        //Here I get a NullPointerException telling me that config field inside context is null
        jsonDeserializer = deserializationContext.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(
            javaType);
      } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      if (jsonDeserializer instanceof StdScalarDeserializer<Object>) {
        System.out.println("Target type is json scalar");
      }
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to find JsonDeserializer for specific JavaType or to find all supported JsonDeserializers?